# Email Not Sending in AWS SES

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-ses

Settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True  
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'  
EMAIL_HOST_USER =  config('SMTP_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =  config('SMTP_PW')
EMAIL_PORT = 587

VERIFIED_IDENTITY = config('VERIFIED_IDENTITY')
```

I have a verified email in my AWS SES and I am trying to send a message. I get a sent message everytime I use my contact form but no message actually gets sent.

```
        if 'contactForm' in request.POST:
            #print('Contact form')
            contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            if contact_form.is_valid():
                contact_form.save()
                email_subject = f'New contact {contact_form.cleaned_data["email"]}: {contact_form.cleaned_data["subject"]}'
                email_message = contact_form.cleaned_data['message']
                print(email_subject,email_message)
                try:
                    send_mail(email_subject, email_message,settings.VERIFIED_IDENTITY,[settings.VERIFIED_IDENTITY])
                except BadHeaderError: 
                    print('bad')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the issue might be related to DNS  SPF record. See below the link related.

"A sender policy framework (SPF) record is a type of DNS TXT record that lists all the servers authorized to send emails from a particular domain."
https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-spf-record/#:~:text=A%20sender%20policy%20framework%20(SPF,Domain%20Name%20System%20(DNS).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-authentication-spf.html

To set up SPF, you publish a TXT record to the DNS configuration for your domain. This record contains a list of the servers that you authorize to send email from your domain. When an email provider receives a message from your domain, it checks the DNS records for your domain to make sure that the email was sent from an authorized server.

Regards,
Ed.